# SWIFT 4 - Cannot convert value of type 'UITextField!' to expected argument type 'Double'

Tags: swift, formula, calculator, trigonometry

I am trying to create this basic earth curvature formula, i got it working in playground, but i'm having difficulties getting the distance from a UITextField, from the storyboard which is of type string into a Double so it can be calculated. i have tried downcasting and among other things, and still cannot get it to work.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

// MARK: - IBOutlets

@IBOutlet weak var distanceTextField: UITextField! // Distance from point A to B in miles from textField
@IBOutlet weak var targetHiddenInFeet: UILabel! // Result of earth curvature formula displayed in Label

// MARK: - Variables and Contsants

let inchPerMile : Double = 8 // inch drop per mile (Never changes)


// MARK: - IBActions

@IBAction func calculateButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

let distanceSquared : Double = pow(distanceTextField,2)
let curvatureFormula : Double = inchPerMile * distanceSquared
let convertionInFeet : Double = curvatureFormula / 12
let roundedNumber = String(format: "%.2f", convertionInFeet)

    print(roundedNumber)
    return targetHiddenInFeet.text = roundedNumber

}
```

[image: Press for Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main mistake is that you're trying to convert `UITextField` object to a number but you have to get a value from the text input via `text` [accessor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619635-text). Something like this `let distanceSquared : Double = pow(distanceTextField.text, 2)`.

Second, `text` property is optional, so it's better to check that you have a value, with `guard` statement for example. Something like this `guard let distance = distanceTextField.text else { return }`at the beginning of `func calculateButtonPressed(...)`. In the case of empty input, your function will not be executed (usually it's called 'early return').

Third, it's a good practice to check that the text is a real number (`Double` [function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/2926277-init) returns optional value if you pass `String` and it's nil if the input is not a number), so the final solution may look something like this:

```
@IBAction func calculateButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let distance = Double(distanceTextField.text) else { return }
    let distanceSquared : Double = pow(distance, 2)
    let curvatureFormula : Double = inchPerMile * distanceSquared
    let convertionInFeet : Double = curvatureFormula / 12
    let roundedNumber = String(format: "%.2f", convertionInFeet)

    print(roundedNumber)
    targetHiddenInFeet.text = roundedNumber
}
```

P.S. Also, I removed `return` statement at the end of the function because it's not necessary (your function return `Void` by default).

Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

You must first get the text from the TextField

```
distanceTextField.text
```

Then to convert this to a double you can use the type initialiser like so

```
Double(distanceTextField.text)
```

So the line that reads

```
let distanceSquared : Double = pow(distanceTextField,2)
```

Would become

```
let distanceSquared : Double = pow(Double(distanceTextField.text), 2)
```

Since this initialisation might fail if the text inputted cannot be cast to a Double, the below code would provide safety

```
if let distance = Double(distanceTextField.text!) {
  let distanceSquared : Double = pow(distance, 2)
} else {
  //failed to convert textfield text to a double
}
```